# Difference between double** and &arr, where arr is a double[]

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I am using C. I have a double array like this:

```
double arr[3]={1,2,3};
```

Next, I assumed that a

```
double[]
```

is just like

```
double *,
```

and thus I created this pointer variable:

```
double ** ppdArr = &arr; /* indirection */
```

I planned to dereference it later and access the items in the original array as follows:

```
double* pdArr = *ppdArr; /* dereference */
double value = pdArr[0]; /* access violation, because pdArr is NULL */
```

Why? When using arrays and pointers interchangeably, what is the difference between static vs. dynamic allocation? Or are there other reasons for this error? For example, the following works (as expected):

```
double *arr2 = ... /*allocated through malloc()*/
double ** ppdArr2 = &arr2; /* indirection */
double *pdArr2 = *ppdArr2; /* dereference */
double value2 = pdArr2[0]; /* works */
```

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: `double ** ppdArr = &arr;` shouldn't compile. Post something we can compile?

Comment: Uhm... how can code that doesn't compile crash?

Comment: The point of confusion is that you can use array notation on pointers, even though functionally they are quite different, especially when you get into multiple dimensions.

Comment: @Pubby @NikBougalis: The code `double ** ppdArr = &arr;` compiles. Here is the code in ideone (gcc-4.8.1): [link](http://ideone.com/oT9vKR): it compiles, but makes runtime error.